# Linky - EDF - Backfeeding feature

Tags: ac-power

In France they are deploying Linky Line Meters. If in a future state energy store/home energy production becomes more mainstream, are there built features of this device to measure current that is back fed into the electric grid?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Linky power meters are able to count both power received from the grid ("puissance soutirée" in French) and power injected back to the grid ("puissance injectée").

[This document from Enedis](https://www.enedis.fr/sites/default/files/Sequelec_GP15_Linky_2017_03_01.pdf) (the electricity distribution network that installs those meters) says:

> - Linky permet l’enregistrement de 2 courbes de charge, l'une en injection et l'autre en soutirage. Ces courbes de charge restituent une puissance moyenne à un pas compris entre 10 et 60 minutes,
> - l’ enregistrement des courbes de charge est inhibé par défaut,
> - en mode consommateur, la capacité est de 3600 enregistrements pour la courbe de charge en soutirage,
> - en mode producteur, la capacité est de 1800 enregistrements pour chacune des 2 courbes de charge.

which translates to:

- Linky can record 2 power graphs, one in injection and the other in draw. These graphs show an average power with a step ranging between 10 and 60 minuets
- Recording is disabled by default
- In consumer mode, the capacity is 3600 records for the draw graph
- In producer mode, the capacity is 1800 records for each of the 2 graphs

That document does not give much details about what information is/can be sent to the network, but as it is known that it sends usage data, it seems obvious that it will send both.

There's also an interface (wired or wireless) that can be added from the meter to your home to receive the information (known as "TIC" or "Télé Information Client"), see page 24 of the document. There are two versions of the information, once of which includes the injected power measurements.